# Converting from fractional to decimal representation in Octave

Tags: octave

I'm getting the following warning:

```
warning: Using rat() heuristics for double-precision input (is this what you wanted?)
```

and my resultant calculation is using the rational approach when I would like the decimal form. How can I force the computation to convert the rational to a decimal representation?

Here is the code:

```
pkg load symbolic
syms a b c d real
C = [1, 0, 0, 0; 0, 1, 0, 0; 0, 0, 0, 1; 0, 0, 1, 0]
H = (1/sqrt(2))*[1, 1; 1, -1]
I = [1, 0; 0, 1]
X = [a, b, c, d]

s = kron(H, I)
s*C*X'
```

Comment: The rational representation seems to be hard-coded in @sym/sym.m (see line 251; the flag returned from the private function @sym/private/const_to_python_str.m seems to be 0 by default, unless an exception was raised, though I may be interpreting this wrong). You could try fiddling with @sym/sym.m if you'd like, but no there doesn't seem to be a 'parameter' you can pass to enforce 'float' representation instead. I have also not found any function that converts the rational representation to a 'float' one (@sym/double.m looked promising as a name, but it gave me an error when I tried it here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rational representation can be converted to a float one using [**`vpa`**](https://octave.sourceforge.io/symbolic/function/vpa.html). `vpa(x,n)` evaluates `x` to at least `n` significant digits. If you want to use current value of [`digits`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/symbolic/function/digits.html), you can omit `n`.

```matlab
vpa(s*C*X.',4)   
% Above line evaluates the result to at least 4 significant digits
```

<sup>Also note that [`'`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Arithmetic-Ops.html#XREFctranspose) is not transpose. It is complex conjugate transpose. Use transpose (i.e. [`.'`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Arithmetic-Ops.html#XREFtranspose)) when you are meant to take transpose. That's why I made the replacement in the above code.</sup>

---

Regarding the warning message, it can be [turned off](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Enabling-and-Disabling-Warnings.html#Enabling-and-Disabling-Warnings) by:

```
warning ('off', 'OctSymPy:sym:rationalapprox');
```

You can turn it on again by replacing `off` with `on` in the above code.